# onmouseover not triggering more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onmouseover

I have a function which is called `onmouseover` that animates the element that was moused over down then, once the mouse has moved outside of the area that the element took up, animates the element back up. The function works fine but only works one time. So if I `mouseover` a second time the function is not triggered. I have to refresh the page in order to get the function to trigger again. Any assistance would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="frontDivcenter blueGradient shadow" id="front1" onmouseover="slideDown(this);">
        Hello
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function slideDown(item) {
    $(item).animate({
        top: '-100%'
    }, 250, 'easeInOutCubic');
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (e.pageX < $(item).offset().left || e.pageX > ($(item).offset().left + $(item).width()) || e.pageY < $(item).offset().top || e.pageY > ($(item).offset().top + $(item).height())) {
            $(item).animate({
                top: '-200%'
            }, 250, 'easeInOutCubic');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I'd say that using percents instead of pixels for your animation is the problem.

Comment: Why are you binding mousemove event to the document every time `slideDwon` is called? They will just keep stacking up and soon your page will become really slow because so much stuff is done every time the mouse moves. You are also unbinding the `onmouseover` event from the element. Maybe you meant to unbind `mousemove` from `document`? Then it's `$(document).unbind("mousemove")`

Comment: sorry, the $(item).unbind() wasn't supposed to be included. I removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unbinding the `mouseover` from the element, not `mousemove` from `document`

Try with:

```
function slideDown(item) {
    $item = $(item);
    $item.animate({
        top: '-100%'
    }, 250, 'easeInOutCubic');

    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        var offset = $item.offset(),
            width = $item.width(),
            height= $item.height();

        if (e.pageX < offset.left || e.pageX > ( offset.left + width) || e.pageY < offset.top || e.pageY > (offset.top + height )) {

            $(document).unbind("mousemove");

            $item.animate({
                top: '-200%'
            }, 250, 'easeInOutCubic' );
        }
    });
}
```